# A problem about $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit where the target is to find $\delta$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The fuction is:

$f(x)=2-\frac{1}{x}$

It requires to find $\delta$ such that $0<\mid x-1 \mid<\delta$ else, $\mid f(x)-1 \mid<0.1$

My process so far, has been trying to compare the stuff that I have, because I found the $\delta$ like that before, but I don't know how to continue with this especific problem.

What I have:

$\mid 2-\frac{1}{x}-1\mid<0.1$

$\mid 1-\frac{1}{x}\mid<0.1$

$\mid\frac{x-1}{x}\mid<0.1$

$\frac{\mid x-1\mid}{\mid x\mid}<0.1$

$\mid x-1 \mid<0.1\mid x \mid$

From here, I don't know how to proceed. The answer in the book says that $\delta=\frac{1}{11}$

Comment: I didn't quite get $\delta=1/11$ but here's what I have. From triangle inequality, $|x|\le |x-1| + 1$ which gives $|x-1|<0.1|x-1| + 0.1$. Rearranging this yields $|x-1|<\frac{0.1}{0.9} = \frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: Your wording with the word "else" looks wrong to me. I would suggest that you are required to "find $\delta$ such that if $0 < |x-1| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - 1| < .01$."

Comment: @CheeHan I'm lost after the "Rearranging this yields".

Comment: What he means is that $\mid x-1 \mid<0.1\mid x-1 \mid+0.1$. Let y=$\mid x-1\mid$. Then we have $y<0.1y+0.1$ Solve for y.

Answer (score 3):

First, choose $\delta<1$ so that we have

\begin{eqnarray}
|x-1|&<&\delta\\
-\delta<x-1&<&\delta\\
1-\delta&<&x<1+\delta\\
0&<&x
\end{eqnarray}

Then we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\left\vert f(x)-1\right\vert&<&\frac{1}{10}\quad\text{ iff}\\
\left\vert 2-\frac{1}{x}-1\right\vert&<&\frac{1}{10}\quad\text{ iff}\\
\left\vert 1-\frac{1}{x}\right\vert&<&\frac{1}{10}\quad\text{ iff}\\
-\frac{1}{10}<1-\frac{1}{x}&<&\frac{1}{10}\quad\text{ iff}\\
-\frac{1}{10}-1<-\frac{1}{x}&<&\frac{1}{10}-1\quad\text{ iff}\\
-\frac{11}{10}<-\frac{1}{x}&<&-\frac{9}{10}\quad\text{ iff}\\
\frac{11}{10}>\frac{1}{x}&>&\frac{9}{10}\quad\text{ iff}\\
\frac{9}{10}<\frac{1}{x}&<&\frac{11}{10}
\end{eqnarray}

which is equivalent to the previous inequality.

So the reciprocals are related in the reverse order

$$ \frac{10}{11}<x<\frac{10}{9} $$

Subtract $1$ to get

$$ -\frac{1}{11}<x-1<\frac{1}{9}$$
So we should choose $|x-1|<\dfrac{1}{11}$

This gives us

$$ -\frac{1}{11}<x-1<\frac{1}{11} $$

And since $\dfrac{1}{11}<\dfrac{1}{9}$ we have

$$-\frac{1}{11}<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{9}$$

which is equivalent to

$$ \left\vert f(x)-1\right\vert<\frac{1}{10} $$

provided it is true that

$$|x-1|<\dfrac{1}{11}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, man. But, I'm a little lost after the "So". I don't quite get the first line and beyond

Comment: And, to be honest I haven't undertood the means to choose a delta. Is it arbitrary?

Comment: Each inequality after the "So" follows from the inequality above it. I had to break them up into two inequalities, do a step and then put the two inequalities back together. Try breaking the inequalities into two separate inequalities and see if you figure out which steps were left out.

Comment: I have rearranged the inequalities to make them (hopefully) easier to follow, and added a bit more at the end.

Comment: See if, using any $0<\epsilon<1$ you can repeat these steps to show that you can let $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$.